# why spark executor did not load the udf class into jvm when using udf registered in dirver?

Tags: apache-spark, user-defined-functions, executor

I run `spark-sql --master yarn` command to lanuch a `SparkSubmit` process， when I registered a udf named `AesCode` and used it by `select AesCode(name) from mytable`, I found that the `Executor(YarnCoarseGrainedExecutorBackend)` jvm did not load the udf class while task is running on Executor machine. I did not understand that.

I think that the executor should load the class for the UDF before it can be used

Comment: Welcome! Can you please share the code you executed? Without it we can't know what really happened :)